# Leaflet - Create custom button to draw

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm working in a project where is needed to draw polygonal shape. To achive my goal I'm using Leaflet Draw, I already disabled all draw tools except polygon tool, now I need just to customize the tool's icon of the button, I searched a lot but I didn't understand how customize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless somebody comes with something clever, you have to provide an icon (26px) and change the button style.

```
<style>
.leaflet-draw-toolbar a.leaflet-draw-draw-polyline {
    background-image: url('icon26.png');
    background-size: 26px;
    background-position: 0;
}
</style>
```

Here is an [example](https://yafred.github.io/leaflet-tests/20170206-customize-leaflet-draw/)

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the heads up.